# Play a video when clicking a button

Tags: android

I have a problem with an app that plays a video after a button is clicked. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonPlayVideo2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        String uriPath2 = "android.resource://AsaDeBineIi"+R.raw.asadebineii2;
        Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
        mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
        mVideoView2.requestFocus();
        mVideoView2.start();
        buttonPlayVideo2.setOnClickListenr(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

                String uriPath = "android.resource://AsaDeBineIi/" + R.raw.asadebineii2;
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
                mVideoView2.requestFocus();
                mVideoView2.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I really don't know what the problem is. I tried to change the format of the video but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that when I upload the apk on the device, the message "can;t play this video" pops out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`String uriPath2="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.asadebineii2;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I changed that and when I start the app, the video starts playing. But when I click the button, the message still pops out. What should I do?

Comment: if you want the video to restart when the button is clicked 'videoView.seekTo(0);
videoView.start();`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!